# Does it available to use `disableCSSOMInjection` with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I'd like to use `disableVendorPrefixes` and `disableCSSOMInjection` which are introduced by v5 with TypeScript.
But, when I use it, there is a typescript error. (`TS2769: No overload matches this call.`)
It seems @types/styled-components doesn't support v5 but is there any way to use these?

versions:
"styled-components": "^5.0.0"
"@types/styled-components": "^4.4.2",

ref. https://styled-components.com/docs/api#stylesheetmanager

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they've updated the types. It's working fine for me right now. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/styled-components